# Pass information from one web page to another page through jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose we have two web pages in Classified car website:

One is search page that has list of all the cars. [Sample website search page](https://www.cardekho.com/used-cars+in+india)

Another page is details page that has details of a particular car. [Sample details page](https://www.cardekho.com/used-car-details/used-Ford-Ecosport-2013-2015-1.5-DV5-MT-Titanium-cars-Navi-Mumbai_1247631.htm)

Now when user clicks on the search page listing, before we navigate to details page, I want to append some parameter to the details page url which i want to access at the details page.

Basically i want to pass information from one web page to another page.

Currently what we do is we append required parameter to details page url when user clicks on details link on used car page.

Now as the number of parameters are growing we are thinking if its right approach to do it that way or we should do something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the extra parameters are specific to the ID of the car, you don't need to pass them from page to page, you can get them from doing a database lookup on the details page.

If the extra parameters come from choices the user makes somewhere, they could be stored in the session and not passed from page to page.

In other cases, you will need to send those parameters to the server, either by querystring as you are doing now, or by submitting a form, which is your other option if your use case for the parameters isn't one of the two above.

Comment: No its not something we can fetch from DB at details page. Actually we want parameters like display rank of the car on search page- this and similar other parameter needs to be passed. We are currently passing them as query string. But we felt we are making URL lengthy which might have some bad impact (I am not sure if any bad gonna happen). For other choice, submitting a form- i understand you mean POST request by this- but in review someone pointed that it would be slow to do it this way.

So we have three choices-query string in url, post request or using session level cookie. Suggestions?

Comment: In your case I'd stick with query string.  Google search results use it just fine with many parameters.

Comment: Does it have any potential to harm SEO or any other rank since we are changing the URL?

Comment: Great question!  However nothing to do with this question, and totally out of my area of expertise.